# Can't access ip 0.0.0.0 and ip 127.0.0.1

Tags: python, flask

There's no problem with the code, but it doesn't work.

The same applies when i change the port number or turn off the firewall.

I'm sorry if there's a problem because this question was written with a translator.

I've already tried many ways on the Internet.

[image]

```
# file name : index.py
# pwd : /project_name/app/main/index.py
 
from flask import Blueprint, request, render_template, flash, redirect, url_for
from flask import current_app as app
 
main= Blueprint('main', __name__, url_prefix='/')

@main.route('/main', methods=['GET'])
def index():
      return render_template('/main/index.html')
```

```
# file name : __init__.py
# pwd : /project_name/app/__init__.py

from flask import Flask
 
app= Flask(__name__)
from app.main.index import main as main
app.register_blueprint(main)
```

```
<!--file name : index.html-->
<!--pwd : /project_name/app/templates/main/index.html-->
<html>
    <head>
        This is Main page Head
    </head>
    <body>
        This is Main Page Body
    </body>
</html>
```

```
# file name : run.py
# pwd : /project_name/run.py
 
from app import app

app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=80)
```

```
 * Serving Flask app "app" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
 * Running on http://0.0.0.0:80/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)

/error code/

http://0.0.0.0:80/ access > ERR_ADDRESS_INVALID
```

or

```
127.0.0.1 - - [21/May/2021 06:41:30] "GET /show HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

Comment: error shows problem with getting `/show` because you don't have `.route('/show'` in your code.

Comment: what ports did you try? Some ports can be blocked by system. Especially ports lower then 1024. Usually code works with default port used by Flask - `5000` or `8000`

Comment: I'm not sure but you can get `ERR_ADDRESS_INVALID` when other program already use this port.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. But the .route('/show') didn't work either. I have also used ports of 80, 8000, 8080 and 5000, but it has not been solved. It's hard. (T.T)

Comment: check if it works with `127.0.0.1`. If works then problem with `0.0.0.0` has nothing to do with Flask but only with system and it probably it may need to search solution in different place - ie. [Network Engineering](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/) or maybe [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/). BTW and you could use `route("/")` instead of `route("/main")`

Comment: I used route("/") as your advice. It works! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, [`0.0.0.0`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/0.0.0.0) means all the IPV4 addresses on the local machine. But sometimes it doesn't (especially in windows machines).

If you are trying to start the server and access local try

```
app.run(host="127.0.0.1", port=80)
```

Comment: Thank you for your opinion. I tried, but the following error occurred: I need to think about whether the laptop settings or Wi-Fi can be a problem.
127.0.0.1 - - [21/May/2021 22:37:13] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [21/May/2021 22:37:14] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 -